# Linux "Download" Folder

Tags: ubuntu, download

If I use the `wget` command in terminal, where does the file download to?  I tried using in terminal I can navigate to `cd Downloads` but when I try to run the `Dir` command to view a list of files nothing is returned.  Also, I can not find this folder by simply navigating the folder hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It downloads to the *directory* where you issue the command.

After downloading it simply issue the command `ls -lrt` and it will show the content of your directory. The downloaded file will be the last on the list.

Answer (score 0):

Like most Linux commands, (after downloading) the file is saved to the current directory unless otherwise specified.